# MySQL delete issue with NULL

Tags: mysql

We have found an issue with deleting records, which seems to be down to specific versions of MySQL. However I can't find any mention of this issue to know when it was fixed.

Some code was trying to do a delete where the primary key is NULL (which should never occur), with code generated from a framework. MySQL deleted a previously inserted row, with a valid not null primary key.

Can demonstrate the issue here.

Test table:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fred_delete` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Then execute the following sql:-

```
INSERT INTO fred_delete
(id, test)
VALUES
(NULL, 'a'),
(NULL, 'b'),
(NULL, 'c'),
(NULL, 'd'),
(NULL, 'e'),
(NULL, 'f'),
(NULL, 'g');

DELETE FROM fred_delete WHERE id IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM fred_delete;
```

On 5.1.58-log mysql install this inserts 7 rows then deletes the first inserted row. On  5.6.12-log install this inserts 7 rows and doesn't delete any.

Does anyone know what versions of MySQL are subject to this behavior? Or is this an issue with configuration?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the bug. Does the `id` have a  `NULL` value here in the error situation, or is it the `WHERE id ID NULL` which is at fault? That helps searching in the bug database ;)

Comment: What happens with a `SELECT * FROM fred_delete WHERE id IS NULL` on the buggy system?

Comment: @Wrikken The id is an autoincrement primary key and cannot validly be set to NULL. I have tried googling the bugs site but not found anything.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - interesting idea. Gave it a try and after the delete it returns nothing. However if done instead of the delete it returns a record with a non null id.

Comment: @Kickstart: Okay, so that suggests the problem is specific to `DELETE` statements. I've been scouring the bug history but I find it quite difficult to locate issues in there and nothing's come up yet. It's possible this was one small effect of a wider bug; it's further possible that nobody even _knew_ about it until now, despite it having been fixed as part of such a wider bug. In that case, it may be practically impossible to find the information you're seeking. :(

Comment: You tried this on a different machine, right? [Works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1851e/1)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - thanks for you effort on this. Finding an application bug just took a few people a couple of hours which turned out to be down to this, and it is not something that is easy to search for on sites to help with the issue. It isn't specific to DELETE, rather it seems specific to the first statement after the inserts. This seems to be treating an id of NULL as the value of the last insert id.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I read it as _not_ specific to `DELETE` statements (after all, `SELECT .. WHERE id IS NULL` returns a row if that first row hasn't been  deleted). [I see this bug, perhaps it is related?](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44694).

Comment: For the record, reproduction: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/9cbc0/1

Comment: I had the wrong MySQL version selected in my fiddle.

Comment: @doug65536: That's not the same version of MySQL. The OP already stated the bug was fixed in some version. We're trying to ascertain _which one_.

Comment: @doug65536 - It works fine on the WAMP install on my dev machine, but has this issue on a live server. If you change the MySQL version in SQL Fiddle to 5.1.61 the problem is apparent. But that is interesting as it suggests that it is an issue with that version of MySQL rather than a configuration issue. Thank you.

Comment: @Wrikken: Oh, yes, I misread it. And I think you found it, too. :)

Comment: @Kickstart: I think we already knew it was version-specific, since it changed in your `5.6.12-log`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aha, it's not a bug, it's a feature.

[`sql_auto_is_null`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_auto_is_null):

> If this variable is set to 1 (the default), then after a statement that successfully inserts an automatically generated AUTO_INCREMENT value, you can find that value by issuing a statement of the following form: 
>   SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE auto_col IS NULL

The [default has been changed from 1 to 0 in >= 5.5.3](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_auto_is_null)

[It is mentioned in MySQL's bug database](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44694), but that was someone equally unaware as us of this feature.

Comment: (I suggest linking to bug 44694 in this answer: even though this is not a bug, that is the post on the bug DB that's equivalent to this question on SO, which I think may hold some value.)